# Does the arithmetic derivative have a geometric interpretation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The standard derivative, for example $\frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x, $ gives the slope of a function at a particular point. Does the arithmetic derivative have a similarly simple geometric interpretation?

As a specific example, how might I show graphically that $1'=0$, that $2'=1$ or that $8'=12$?

EDIT: The arithmetic derivative can be defined as follows:

$p'=1$ for any prime, $p$

$(pq)'= p'q + pq'$ for any $p,q \in  \mathbb{N}$

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative))

From the above, rules analogous to the power and quotient rules can be derived.

For a frenetic introduction, please see this YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/9iPmyl0vaas).

Comment: What is this "arithmetic derivative", exactly?

Comment: I will add more detail. I thought it might be an obscure topic.

Comment: @AdamHrankowski what actually we have to do in this question?

Comment: You know how you can graph a function and draw the tangent line at a point. You can say, "The slope of this line is the same as the derivative at this point." Is there a picture you can draw and say, "This picture helps you see the meaning of the arithmetic derivative"?

Comment: Further discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/3Blue1Brown/comments/a90drf/is_there_a_visual_interpretation_of_the/?utm_source=reddit-android